# _launchURL gets launched when my widget gets build

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the url_launcher package to launch urls in my app.

I have many links that I need to launch with separate buttons.

However when I load my stateless widget it launches the "_launchURL" function and opens up https://www.yahoo.com immediately.

I believe this have something todo with the widget being called when it gets created. But the function inside "onPressed" should not be called before an actual press, right?

```
class myStateless extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
            button("Link 1", "https://www.yahoo.com"),
            button("Link 2", "https://www.google.com"),
        ]
    );
  }
}

Widget button(String text, String url) {
    return RaisedButton(
        child: Text(text),
        onPressed: _launchURL(url),
      );
}

_launchURL(url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

I then get the error: 
`type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, You have to just change at your ***button()*** creation method like,

`onPressed: _launchURL(url)` TO `onPressed: () => _launchURL(url),`

That's it.

Comment: Out of interest, do you know why this happens? I realise that the latter is the callback from onPressed, but why does the former call the function by default?

Comment: I think If method has parameter and if you set on  "onPressed" directly then you must need to call as my answer but If your method has no any parameter then you can directly write as `onPressed: _launchURL`. It will call after press button.

Answer (score 1):

There are huge difference between `_launchURL`, and `_launchURL(url)`.

If you set `_launchURL(url)` at button click event without button pressed method you are calling method, and if you pass `_launchURL` it passes just instance of method which will execute at call of the button.